# i m trying to play mp3 from tableview while user select table row song need to play

Tags: iphone, uitableview, avfoundation, xcode4.6

//i have take 2 song 's array

```
nsmutablearray *  enrique = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        [enrique addObject:@"add.mp3"];
        [enrique addObject:@"hero.mp3"];

// this section of uitableview didselectrow 

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
             cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

      cellText = cell.textLabel.text;

      lbl.text=cellText;

     player=[passarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       NSLog(@"mp3 %@",player);
      //  [passarray indexOfObject:player];
        [self.player prepareToPlay];
       // [player play];

         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    songNumber = indexPath.row;
    [self loadPlayer:songNumber];
}


-(void)loadPlayer:(int)songIndex
{
    if(songIndex <= 0)
    {
        [previousButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
    if(songIndex+1 >= self.arySongsList.count)
    {
        [nextButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
    if(songIndex < self.arySongsList.count)
    {
        NSURL *audioFileLocationURL;
        audioFileLocationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.arySongsList objectAtIndex:songIndex]]];
        NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",audioFileLocationURL]autorelease];
        str = [str lastPathComponent];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%5B" withString:@"["];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%5D" withString:@"]"];
        NSError *error;
        if(songIndex == self.arySongsList.count)
        {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sound18.mp3pk.com/pop_remix/ebodf11/ebodf11-15(www.songs.pk).mp3"];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
        }
        else
        {
            audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
        }
        [audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            [[self volumeControl] setEnabled:NO];
            [[self playPauseButton] setEnabled:NO];
            [[self alertLabel] setText:@"Unable to load file"];
            [[self alertLabel] setHidden:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [[self alertLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has loaded", str]];
            [[self alertLabel] setHidden:NO];
            //Make sure the system follows our playback status
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
            //Load the audio into memory
            [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        }
    }
    if (!self.audioPlayer.playing)
    {
        [self playAudio];
    }
    else if (self.audioPlayer.playing)
    {
        [self pauseAudio];
    }
}
```